# How do you wait for the jQuery each loop to finish before continuing?

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to check the value of all objects of a certain type (in this case a date input) before continuing on but I am seeing the function continue before the loop is complete:

```
function SaveAppointment() {
  
    var maxDate = new Date('12/31/9999');
    $('.customDateField').each(function (i, obj) {
        var date = new Date($(obj).val());
        if (date > maxDate || Number(date.getFullYear()) > 9999) {
            $.toast({
                heading: 'Date Invalid',
                text: "One or more dates on the referral form are invalid.",
                showHideTransition: 'slide',
                bgColor: "#a94442",
                position: "top-center",
                icon: "warning"
            });

            return;
        }
    });

    alert('no go');
    return;
}
```

What is happening is that before it finds the invalid field the alert is popping when it shouldn't ever hit it.

Comment: `$.toast()` is asynchronous, it doesn't wait for the user to dismiss the dialog. So the loop keeps going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toast is asynchronous. It displays the dialogue and returns, it doesn't wait for the user to dismiss it.

Instead of calling toast inside the loop, use the loop to check if there are any invalid inputs, then display the alert at the end.

```js
function SaveAppointment() {
  var maxDate = new Date('12/31/9999');
  if ([...$('.customerDateField')].some(obj => {
      $('.customDateField').each(function(i, obj) {
        var date = new Date($(obj).val());
        return date > maxDate || Number(date.getFullYear()) > 9999;
      })
    })) {
    $.toast({
      heading: 'Date Invalid',
      text: "One or more dates on the referral form are invalid.",
      showHideTransition: 'slide',
      bgColor: "#a94442",
      position: "top-center",
      icon: "warning"
    });

    return;
  }
  alert('no go');
  return;
}
```